Fixing Compilation Errors and Creating an R Function from Rcpp Code
I try to implement RCPP code for the R function below. I'm very new to C++. Below I put R function and the RCPP function. The errors occur in the C++ script lines 43,44,50,51,55.
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// Helper function to extract a row slice from a NumericMatrix
NumericVector extract_row_slice(const NumericMatrix& data, int row, int start, int end) {
  if (end >= data.ncol()) end = data.ncol() - 1;
  NumericVector slice(end - start + 1);
  for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    slice[i - start] = data(row, i);
  }
  return slice;
}

// Main function to compute critical values
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector crit_val_cpp(int reps, int k, int n, double Quantile, double eps) {
  NumericVector W(reps);
  int sublength = n - 1;
  double n_squared = n * n;
  
  for (int j = 0; j < reps; j++) {
    NumericMatrix data(k, n, Rcpp::rnorm(n * k).begin());
    NumericVector substat(sublength);
    NumericVector scale(sublength);
    
    // Precompute the scaling factor for each t
    for (int i = 0; i < sublength; i++) {
      scale[i] = (i + 1) * (sublength - i) / n_squared;
    }
    
    for (int t = 0; t < sublength; t++) {
      NumericVector mean1(k), mean2(k);
      
      // Calculate means for each segment
      for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        mean1[i] = mean(extract_row_slice(data, i, 0, t));
        mean2[i] = mean(extract_row_slice(data, i, t + 1, n - 1));
      }
      
      // Calculate inter1 and inter2
      NumericMatrix inter1(k, t + 1), inter2(k, n - t - 1);
      for (int h = 0; h < k; h++) {
        NumericVector temp1 = cumsum(extract_row_slice(data, h, 0, t)) - (seq_len(t + 1) - 1) * mean1[h];
        NumericVector temp2 = cumsum(extract_row_slice(data, h, t + 1, n - 1)) - (seq_len(n - t - 1) - 1) * mean2[h];
        std::copy(temp1.begin(), temp1.end(), inter1(h, _).begin());
        std::copy(temp2.begin(), temp2.end(), inter2(h, _).begin());
      }
      
      // Compute M1 and M2 matrices
      NumericMatrix M1 = inter1.t() * inter1 / n_squared;
      NumericMatrix M2 = inter2.t() * inter2 / n_squared;
      
      // Calculate substat[t] using the quadratic form
      NumericVector diff = scale[t] * (mean1 - mean2);
      substat[t] = n * crossprod(diff, solve(M1 + M2, diff));
    }
    
    // Store the maximum of the substatistics adjusted for eps
    int lower_idx = floor(n * eps);
    int upper_idx = ceil(n * (1 - eps)) - 1;
    W[j] = max(abs(substat[Range(lower_idx, upper_idx)]));
  }
  
  // Return W 
  return W;
}


This RCPP function returns W. I would use W to get the critical values as in the R script below. Here is the R script;
library(Rcpp)
crit.val <- function(reps, k, n, Quantile, eps){
  W         <- rep(0,reps)
  sublength <- n-1
  scale     <- (1:(n-1))/n^2*((n-1):1)
  
  for (j in 1:reps){
    data    <- matrix( rnorm(n*k, 0, 1), k, n )
    substat <- rep(0, sublength)
    for (t in 1:(n-1)){
      if (k==1){
        mean1 <- mean( data[1, 1:t] )
        mean2 <- mean( data[1, (1+t):n] )
      }
      if (k>1){
        mean1 <- apply( matrix(data[,     1:t], ncol = t),   1, mean )
        mean2 <- apply( matrix(data[, (t+1):n], ncol = n-t), 1, mean )
      }
      inter1 <- NULL
      inter2 <- NULL
      for (h in 1:k){
        inter1 <- rbind(inter1, cumsum( data[h, 1:t    ] ) - (1:t)*mean1[h])
        inter2 <- rbind(inter2, cumsum( data[h, n:(t+1)] ) - (1:(n-t))*mean2[h])
      }
      M1 <- inter1 %*% t(inter1)/n^2
      M2 <- inter2 %*% t(inter2)/n^2
      
      substat[t] <- n * matrix(scale[t]*(mean1 - mean2), 1, k) %*% solve(M1+M2) %*% 
                        matrix(scale[t]*(mean1 - mean2), k, 1) 
    }
    W[j] <- max( abs(substat)[ floor(n*eps):ceiling(n*(1-eps)) ] )
    print(j)
    print(Sys.time())
  }
  return( quantile( W, Quantile ) )
}


crit.val(reps=100, k=1, n=100, Quantile = c(0.9,0.95,0.99,0.995,0.999), eps=0.01)

Here are the errors in RCPP script;
-Line 43 invalid operands to binary expression ('sugar::Cumsum<14, true, Vector<14>>' and 'typename traits::enable_if<traits::is_convertible<typename traits::remove_const_and_reference<double>::type, typename traits::storage_type<13>::type>::value, sugar::Times_Vector_Primitive<13, true, Minus_Vector_Primitive<13, false, SeqLen>>>::type' (aka 'Rcpp::sugar::Times_Vector_Primitive<13, true, Rcpp::sugar::Minus_Vector_Primitive<13, false, Rcpp::sugar::SeqLen>>'))

Line 44 invalid operands to binary expression ('sugar::Cumsum<14, true, Vector<14>>' and 'typename traits::enable_if<traits::is_convertible<typename traits::remove_const_and_reference<double>::type, typename traits::storage_type<13>::type>::value, sugar::Times_Vector_Primitive<13, true, Minus_Vector_Primitive<13, false, SeqLen>>>::type' (aka 'Rcpp::sugar::Times_Vector_Primitive<13, true, Rcpp::sugar::Minus_Vector_Primitive<13, false, Rcpp::sugar::SeqLen>>'))

-Line 50 no member named 't' in 'Rcpp::Matrix<14>'
-Line 51no member named 't' in 'Rcpp::Matrix<14>'
-Line 55use of undeclared identifier 'solve'



I initially created a row_slicer function in Rcpp to handle specific errors successfully. However, I've encountered subsequent errors that I'm struggling to resolve, despite attempting to use various troubleshooting methods, including AI tools. My background is primarily in R, and I'm relatively new to C++, which is why I'm finding it challenging to address these issues independently.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance, comments, or assistance in troubleshooting and integrating my Rcpp code into a functional R function.
Thank you in advance for any help!

"The errors occur in the C++ script lines 43,44,50,51,55." -- Can you reduce your code so that the first error occurs on, say, line 4 instead of 43? (Focus on just the first error, and C++ has code, not scripts.) Don't try to show us how to get critical values; show us just what is needed to reproduce the syntax error.

Regarding lines 43,44:
This is because the operator '-' is defined for NumericVector, but not for the type outputted by the cumsum function (Rcpp::sugar::Cumsum<14, true, Rcpp::NumericVector>). In this case it isn't converted implicitly, so you have to do it, like this:

NumericVector temp1 = as<NumericVector>(wrap(cumsum(extract_row_slice(data, h, 0, t)))) - as<NumericVector>(wrap(seq_len(t + 1) - 1)) * mean1[h];

NumericVector temp2 = as<NumericVector>(wrap(cumsum(extract_row_slice(data, h, t + 1, n - 1)))) - as<NumericVector>(wrap(seq_len(n - t - 1) - 1)) * mean2[h];

Bit messy but there you go, implicit conversion has limits.
Regarding your other issues, it looks like you are trying to solve problems better suited to RcppArmadillo. You can transpose and solve matrixes using this library. See:
https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#solve
https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo
Rcpp matrixes simply do not have this functionality.
I hope this helps.

Thanks for your response. It solved part of the error but I'm still experiencing the same issue even after using RcppArmadillo for the remaining errors.

Can you post the error message and some of the armadillo code you wrote? I may be able to help.

https://github.com/Ocalak/RCPP-crtvalue/blob/main/ttt.cpp I guess it is easy to check my github repo. Errors occur on lines 54,54 and 59. Line 54no member named 't' in 'Rcpp::Matrix<14>' : Line 55no member named 't' in 'Rcpp::Matrix<14>':  Line 60no matching function for call to 'solve'.

I don't have the context to run the code. However, you need to change Rcpp::NumericMatrix to arma::mat at line 54 and 55. But doing that I imagine will solve some problems but cause others. You will need to read the armadillo docs, and change some NumericVectors to arma::vecs. The RcppArmadillo package allows  conversion from armadillo vectors to Rcpp ones.
